# Brighness control problem

Tags: brightness, function-keys

I'm using 14.04LTS. The function keys that control brightness have been reversed such that when I press Fn + right arrow key, the brightness reduces and when I press Fn + left arrow key, the brightness increases. How can I fix this?

Comment: some people can't even get that work, you are lucky it works at least! :P

Comment: What is your laptop model?

Answer (score 0):

You can install drivers by doing the following:

1. Click "System Settings"
2. Choose "Software & Updates"
3. In the top right corner click "Additional Drivers"
4. Wait for the list of drivers to load
5. Select the one from Nvidia that says "(proprietary,tested)"